# inserting famo.us container into a wordpress site

Tags: wordpress, famo.us

A recent famo.us newsletter stated they were working on "Crawl: A basic Wordpress site with Famo.us containers sprinkled in."

Is this only possible through wordpress.org, or could you one use famo.us through wordpress.com sites as well? If so, how would one go about inserting a famo.us container into a **wordpress.com** page?

Answer (score 0):

If the theme is supported by wordpress.com, sure. Otherwise, wordpress.com blogs only allow themes they approve so if the theme you're looking for isn't [here](http://theme.wordpress.com/), then it won't be happening.